# wxpython: How to set width and height of a wxnotebook?

Tags: python, wxpython

i am having troubles, with I believe is the sizers. I cannot set the size of the notebook the way i want it to be. Right now I put a button and the position of the button determines the size of the notebook (it will stretch it) however i want it to just be able to do this without using the button. I have played around with it however i cannot get it to change by itself.

Please run the following code if you do not understand what I mean.

```
import random
import wx


[wxID_FRAME1, wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1, wxID_FRAME1BUTTON2, wxID_FRAME1LISTBOX1, 
] = [wx.NewId() for _init_ctrls in range(4)]
########################################################################
class TabPanel(wx.Panel):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        colors = ["red", "blue", "gray", "yellow", "green"]
        self.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(colors))

        sampleList = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
        listBox = wx.ListBox(self, -1, (20, 20), (80, 120), sampleList, wx.LB_SINGLE)
        listBox.SetSelection(3)
        #This is the button!!!!
        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Create new")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(btn,300,400, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    Frame that holds all other widgets
    """

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "Notebook Tutorial",
                          size=(600,400)
                          )
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)
        tabOne = TabPanel(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(tabOne, "things")

        tabTwo = TabPanel(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(tabTwo, "other things")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(400)
        sizer.Add(notebook)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
                        #menu bar
        status=self.CreateStatusBar()
        menubar=wx.MenuBar()
        first=wx.Menu()
        second=wx.Menu()
        first.Append(wx.NewId(),"New","Creates A new file")
        first.Append(wx.NewId(),"ADID","Yo")
        menubar.Append(first,"File")
        menubar.Append(second,"Edit")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        self.Layout()

        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = DemoFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you very so much for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
COLORS = ["red", "blue", "black", "yellow", "green"]
NUMBERS = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
PANELS = ["Things", "More things", "Ultra!"]

import random
import wx

class TabPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(COLORS))
        self.listBox = wx.ListBox(self, size=(200, -1), choices=NUMBERS, style=wx.LB_SINGLE)
#        self.button = wx.Button(self, label="Something else here? Maybe!")

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.listBox, proportion=0, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, border=5)
#        self.sizer.Add(self.button, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)


class MyNotebook(wx.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Notebook.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.panels = []
        for name in PANELS:
            panel = TabPanel(self)
            self.panels.append(panel)
            self.AddPage(panel, name)


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.notebook = MyNotebook(self, size=(400, -1))
#        self.button = wx.Button(self, label="Something else here? Maybe!")

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.notebook, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
#        self.sizer.Add(self.button, proportion=0)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.panel = MyPanel(self)

        self.status = self.CreateStatusBar()

        self.menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        first=wx.Menu()
        second=wx.Menu()
        first.Append(wx.NewId(), "New", "Creates A new file")
        first.Append(wx.NewId(), "ADID", "Yo")
        self.menubar.Append(first, "File")
        self.menubar.Append(second, "Edit")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.Show()


app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None, size=(600, 400))
app.MainLoop()
```

Uncomment the buttons to see how you can add more stuff. You may find some useful hints for your wxPython programming in my code. I am to lazy to describe everything ;-).

Comment: Thanks, but i wanted it to be set at a certain width, however its automatically going for the window width

Comment: @user1008537 - Updated with fixed width. It is however generally recommended to have as less fixed sizes as possible and use sizers for automatic layout. This way your app will not break when system wide options are changed, such as font size etc.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way, to get what tab is open

Comment: Bind change page event: `self.Bind(wx.EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED, self.OnPageChanged)`